# WebRequest, Stream, GetResponse Freezes on Accessing PHP Notification Page VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net, web-services, web, service

```
Can't provide any code
```

Hello,

I have a problem where I am trying to consume a web service. The web service runs in VB.NET and the Client runs on PHP. The server is notifying the client it wants some data, when it tries to access the client page it freezes but when I run the page manually it runs fine and sends all the data to the web service.

I have a Web Request setup, then a Stream which is set as GetResponse.GetResponseStream() and then a new StreamReader. It freezes on GetResponse. The web service is making a GET request with an ID attached.

Any clues? I can provide additional details if required.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem. It was a threading issue where the request was waiting for a response from the website locking all the other threads from receiving the response.

Thanks!